# How to develop multiple modules parallel to the app module in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am developing a large Angular 2 app. For that I need to create a separate module for common core components, services, etc. My main app will be developed in `src/app` directory and I want my core components to be developed in `src/core`. And any future sub projects for this project will be developed in `src/feature`, etc. So the final directory structure will be,

```
MyProject/
    config/
    dist/
    e2e/
    public/
    src/
        app/
        core/
        feature_1/
        feature_2/
    ...
```

How does Angular 2 support this behavior?

PS: I am using latest versions of Angular 2, currently rc-4 (with Angular CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Just create some additional `components` folders in each `feature_x` folders

```
MyProject/
    config/
    dist/
    e2e/
    public/
    src/
        app/
        core/
        feature_1/components
                            /app
                            /search-x
                            /nav-menu
        feature_2/components
    ...
```

Also each components folder would have their own `app` folder with `app.html`

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```